# Openi Plugin for Pentaho not working with mondrian roles

Tags: plugins, mdx, olap, pentaho, mondrian

I have a mondrian schema file with Role configuration, restricting the role only for Central region.

```
<Role name="Central">
    <SchemaGrant access="all">
     <CubeGrant cube="Quadrant Analysis" access="all">
       <HierarchyGrant hierarchy="Region" access="custom" rollupPolicy="partial">
          <MemberGrant member="[Region].[Central]" access="all">
          </MemberGrant>
       </HierarchyGrant>
     </CubeGrant>
    </SchemaGrant>
</Role>
```

In Pentaho, I have a user **central_user** with roles **Authenticated** and **Central**.

Also, uncommented **Mondrian-One-To-One-UserRoleMapper** in **pentahoObjects.spring.xml**

I am evaluating openi and saiku plugins for Pentaho.

In saiku plugin, the analysis report correctly filters and shows only Central Region.

But in the Openi plugin, the report shows all the regions.

Is there any other additional settings required for Openi to make it pass the role information to Mondrian?